# SWI-Prolog, списки

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Помогите пожалуйста, определить отношение, которое формирует из заданного списка новый, состоящий из элементов стоящих на нечетных позициях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьми готовую функцию split, для [разделения списка на элементы с четными и нечетными индексами](http://pro-prof.com/forums/topic/split_list_to_even_odd_indexes) (по ссылке она подробно расписана):

```
split([], [], []):-!.
split([Elem], [Elem], []):-!.
split([Odd, Even|Tail], [Odd|OddTail], [Even|EvenTail]):-
  split(Tail, OddTail, EvenTail).
```

Ну и тогда, все, что тебе остается - вызвать ее как-то так:

```
split(List, OddList, _).
```